# Can I use a shielded multiple conductor cable to carry current (0-100mA) from multiple current transformer clamps (CT) that sense AC current?

Tags: current, transformer, current-transformer, split-phase

I need to run cables for 12 CTs (Split Core Current Transformers) that will be sensing current on multiple branches inside my outdoor electrical panel. In case it matters, it is a 240V split-phase 200A panel (typical USA residential).

Each CT uses UL2457 2 conductor 24AWG shielded cable, however instead of running 12 of them, I was hoping to use multiple 4 or 6 conductor cables between my panel and the exterior box holding the multi-channel energy meter. Except for the 200A CTs, all other CTs do not have burden resistors so the signal will me 0-26mA, but in theory could be 0-100mA depending on which CT I end up using. For the 200A CTs I plan on using a single 2 conductor cable for each given the signal is a low voltage.

It is my understanding that current signals do not interfere with each other so I should be able to have 2 CTs for the same 240V appliance (therefore 1 CT per split-phase) running in a single 4 conductor cable. I want to confirm that there will not be any interference between the two current signals and that the fact they are not on the same phase will not matter.

An alternative, if phase does matter and current signals do not interfere with each other, would be to use a 6 conductor cable so I can wire 3 CTs on the same phase through a single cable (the energy meter has 6ch per board, 3 on each phase). Would this work?

Comment: Should work just fine!

Comment: I agree, both alternatives sound good to me

Comment: Gil & Jens Thank you for confirming.